# Switching Git branches while running in Docker container causes permission error

Tags: django, windows, git, docker

I'm running Docker 19 on Windows 10 for development. A container volume binds directly to a Git repo folder and serves the Django app in that folder. I use Mingw-w64 to run Git (aka Git Bash).

Occasionally, I'll do the following (or something similar to the following):

1. Request a page served by the Docker container. (To replicate an error, for example.)
2. Switch to a different branch.
3. Request a page served by the Docker container from the new branch.
4. Switch to a different branch.

On the last branch switch, Git will freeze for a bit and then say permission denied on a particular file. The file is a difference between the two branches, so Git is trying to change it.

Process Explorer tells me the files are used by the `system` process so the only way to get it to let go is by restarting.

My gut is telling me the Django web process (`manage.py runserver`) is likely locking the file until the request connection is fully closed and is probably lingering as an established connection.

Is my gut right? If it is... Why is the lock held by the `system` process and not Docker? Is there anything to do to check before I do a branch change? Is there any way to prevent it from happening at all?